# Threejs scene gets smaller with window height

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm building a scene and I noticed that when the canvas resizes horizontally, the view retains its height, which is good, but when I resize the canvas vertically, the scene sort of zooms out.  How can I keep it from zooming out, so the rock faces are always at the edges of the screen?

I'm not sure the proper terminology to describe it so here are some screenshots:

*Desktop - This is how I want it to look*
[image: Desktop scene]

*Mobile - This is fine too, the sides cut off*
[image: mobile scene]

*Window resized vertically - it zooms the scene out, breaking the illusion.  The rocks should be on the edges of the view*
[image: panoramic scene]

Comment: Is this a use case for https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#center?

Comment: What you need to do, when the size of screen ratio is higher than a certain point (ex: 16/9), you need to diminish the field of view (FOV) of your camera proportionally.
You will need to a bit of knowledge about how FOV works https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view
And also documentation reading https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.setFocalLength